# Fire Wordpress shortcode in dynamically loaded Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a great deal of modals on one page, and I'm trying to get them to be dynamically loaded to improve performance on the page.  The problem I'm running into is that a lot of the modals have shortcode for a carousel plugin we're using, so of course it's not loading when it's dynamically loaded.  Is there any way around this?  Here's the code for the "blank slate" modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="padding-right:0px !important;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I'm loading into it:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <!-- Header Code -->
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="wondermodal">
        <div style="max-width:450px; margin:0 auto;">
            <!-- Shortcode that's giving me grief -->
            [wonderplugin_carousel id="33"]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:50px;">
        <!-- Rest of the Body Code -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <!-- Footer Code -->
</div>
```

And here's the JavaScript I'm using to load it:

```
jQuery('.openModal').click(function (event) {
    jQuery('.modal-content').load(/*Url of modal content*/);
});
```

Any insight on how I could fire this shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping it in PHP tags and running like

`<?= do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_carousel id="33"]');?>`

Is it an option for you?

Comment: I tried that, and for some reason it just stops the entire file from being loaded.  It opens the modal, but none of the content from the other URL is loaded.  There aren't any errors on the console to help me figure out why, either.

Comment: And when you access that url direclty are the contents being there?

What shows up in the debug.log? Are those modal files aware of wordpress or this snippets shows them fully?

I am not sure if this could be the reason but if the answer for above question is no then try something like that. Add this snippet on top of your modal file
`<?php include '../../../wp-load.php'; ?>` where the path to wp-load.php is proper for your scenario